# Resume interrupted Debian live build

Tags: debian, live-usb

I am using Debian live build to customize my own setup. The basic commands are simple: `sudo lb clean`, followed by `lb config`, and then `sudo lb build`. The problem is that if a build session is interrupted for any reason, e.g. network failure or a `W: Failed to fetch` error because of an unreachable package mirror, I have to restart from scratch. Obviously, this is not efficient. Is there a way to simply resume from an interrupted `sudo lb build` session?